# After Postback make at least 1 out of 5 textboxed required

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, postback, requiredfieldvalidator

I have 1 checkbox and 5 textboxes.

When I checked the checkbox, at least 1 out of 5 textboxes (either of 5) should be required.

Please help :(

Thank you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What does your code look like and what have you tried already?

Comment: @lc. my question is how am i going to do it in client side.

Comment: @sekky nope i havent tried it yet., cant think of any applicable work around for it. can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the require field validator for example.
check out this (there's also an example): http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_reqfieldvalidator.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="Click me"  runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="Required()" 
                Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Required() {
            //debugger;
            var checkboxId = $("#CheckBox1");
            if (checkboxId != null) {
                if (checkboxId[0].checked) {
                    if ($("#TextBox1").val() == "" && $("#TextBox2").val() == "" && $("#TextBox3").val() == "" && $("#TextBox4").val() == "" && $("#TextBox5").val() == "") {
                        EnableValidator("RequiredFieldValidator1");
                    }
                    else {
                        DisableValidator("RequiredFieldValidator1");
                     }

                }

            }
        }

        function EnableValidator(id) {
            if ($('#' + id)[0] != undefined) {
                ValidatorEnable($('#' + id)[0], true);
                $('#' + id).hide();
            }
        }

        function DisableValidator(id) {
            if ($('#' + id)[0] != undefined) {
                ValidatorEnable($('#' + id)[0], false);
            }
        }


    </script>


Here is complete sample.. Hopefully this will help
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on client side then use *javascript* for it.

simply check that if the checkbox is checked then textbox value should not be null. some of the code would be like this.

```
<script>
function(){
var check = document.getElementById('yourcheckbox');
if (check.checked){
var check = document.getElementById('yourtextbox1');
if (check.value.trim()==""){
alert("your error message for textbox here");
return false;
}
else{
return true;
}
}
else{
alert("your error message for checkbox here");
return false;
}
};
</script>
```

hope this will give you some help :D